# Wrapping urllib3.HTTPResponse in io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

I use AWS `boto3` library which returns me an instance of `urllib3.response.HTTPResponse`. That response is a subclass of `io.IOBase` and hence behaves as a binary file. Its `read()` method returns `bytes` instances.

Now, I need to decode `csv` data from a file received in such a way. I want my code to work on both `py2` and `py3` with minimal code overhead, so I use `backports.csv` which relies on `io.IOBase` objects as input rather than on py2's `file()` objects.

The first problem is that `HTTPResponse` yields `bytes` data for CSV file, and I have `csv.reader` which expects `str` data.

```
>>> import io
>>> from backports import csv  # actually try..catch statement here
>>> from mymodule import get_file

>>> f = get_file()  # returns instance of urllib3.HTTPResponse
>>> r = csv.reader(f)
>>> list(r)
Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I tried to wrap `HTTPResponse` with `io.TextIOWrapper` and got error `'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'read1'`. This is expected becuase `TextIOWrapper` is intended to be used with `BufferedIOBase` objects, not `IOBase` objects. And it only happens on `python2`'s implementation of `TextIOWrapper` because it always expects underlying object to have `read1` ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/_io/textio.c#L1429)), while `python3`'s implementation checks for `read1` existence and falls back to `read` gracefully ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/_io/textio.c#L1495)).

```
>>> f = get_file()
>>> tw = io.TextIOWrapper(f)
>>> list(csv.reader(tw))
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'read1'
```

Then I tried to wrap `HTTPResponse` with `io.BufferedReader` and then with `io.TextIOWrapper`. And I got the following error:

```
>>> f = get_file()
>>> br = io.BufferedReader(f)
>>> tw = io.TextIOWrapper(br)
>>> list(csv.reader(f))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

After some investigation it turns out that the error only happens when the file doesn't end with `\n`. If it does end with `\n` then the problem does not happen and everything works fine.

There is some additional logic for closing underlying object in `HTTPResponse` ([source](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/response.py#L385)) which is seemingly causing the problem.

**The question is:** how can I write my code to

- work on both python2 and python3, preferably with no try..catch or version-dependent branching;
- properly handle CSV files represented as `HTTPResponse` regardless of whether they end with `\n` or not?

One possible solution would be to make a custom wrapper around `TextIOWrapper` which would make `read()` return `b''` when the object is closed instead of raising `ValueError`. But is there any better solution, without such hacks?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is an interface mismatch between `urllib3.HTTPResponse` and `file` objects. It is described in [this `urllib3` issue #1305](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/1305#issuecomment-355078789).

For now there is no fix, hence I used the following wrapper code which seemingly works fine:

```
class ResponseWrapper(io.IOBase):
    """
    This is the wrapper around urllib3.HTTPResponse
    to work-around an issue shazow/urllib3#1305.

    Here we decouple HTTPResponse's "closed" status from ours.
    """
    # FIXME drop this wrapper after shazow/urllib3#1305 is fixed

    def __init__(self, resp):
        self._resp = resp

    def close(self):
        self._resp.close()
        super(ResponseWrapper, self).close()

    def readable(self):
        return True

    def read(self, amt=None):
        if self._resp.closed:
            return b''
        return self._resp.read(amt)

    def readinto(self, b):
        val = self.read(len(b))
        if not val:
            return 0
        b[:len(val)] = val
        return len(val)
```

And use it as follows:

```
>>> f = get_file()
>>> r = csv.reader(ResponseWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedReader(f))))
>>> list(r)
```

The similar fix was proposed by `urllib3` maintainers in the bug report comments but it would be a breaking change hence for now things will probably not change, so I have to use wrapper (or do some monkey patching which is probably worse).